# Piping ping through awk and redirecting output to a file

Tags: linux, shell, awk

My idea is to *constantly* ping an address, extract some information, and write that to a file.

This is what I've tried:

```
$ ping google.com | awk -F' ' '{ time = split($8, arr, "time="); print arr[2] }' > file.log
```

Then wait a couple of seconds and do:

```
$ file file.log
file.log: empty
```

However, this works as expected (prints `time=` for each line in the ping output):

```
$ ping google.com | awk -F' ' '{ time = split($8, arr, "time="); print arr[2] }'
```

This works too:

```
$ echo "64 bytes from some.net (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=16.7 ms" | awk -F' ' '{ time = split($8, arr, "time="); print arr[2] }' > file.log
$ cat file.log
16.7
```

And this works:

```
$ ping -c 1 google.com | awk -F' ' '{ time = split($8, arr, "time="); print arr[2] }' > file.log
```

It is only when I keep ping going that it does not work. My `file.log` remains empty.

How can I achieve that ping constantly runs and fills my `file.log`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Output to stdout is usually buffered - nothing is written until the buffer is full. Output to stderr is usually written immediately.

You could try:

```
ping google.com |\
awk 'sub("time=","",$8) { print $8 >"/dev/stderr" }' 2>file.log
```

or:

```
ping google.com |\
awk ' sub("time=","",$8) { print $8; fflush() }' >file.log
```

Comment: Ah... Buffering again. `flush()` does the job.